# Played with some lead solder without washing my hands for awhile, should I be concerned?

Tags: soldering, safety

I was using some lead solder at work, and wasn't aware it was lead solder nor had anyone told me that it can be dangerous.

For the most part I was just handling it. This was last week and I don't think I washed my hands afterward.

I know this may be silly, but is that anything I should be concerned over? I can't imagine my low exposure would be worrisome, it's probably something that multiple hours every day for years would cause issues over, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: You said it yourself in the final paragraph. Also don't assume that lead-free solder is any safer than leaded. It just traded one type of toxicity for another.

Comment: I (and many others) worked with leaded solder for many years without any great concern about lead contamination.  Leaded solder has only become hazardous recently, since lead-free solder was introduced.  :-)

Comment: Many years.  The most significant effect is a life-long curiosity and love of electronics.  If you've joined this site, you've probably already been affected :-)

Comment: @PeterBennett -- then why are all your words mispelled??  ;)

Comment: @ScottSeidman 5 years on - What is pelling? :-)

Answer (score 6):

Lead solder is not all that bad- it's cumulative exposure that can cause problems.

[Here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/MSDS/Kester/245%20Core%20Sn63Pb37.pdf) is the MSDS (Material Safety Data Sheet) for a typical tin-lead solder. It says, in part,

> Keep away from foodstuffs, beverages and feed.
>   Immediately remove all soiled and contaminated clothing.
>   Wash hands before breaks and at the end of work.

Note also that, as @MattYoung says, the "no-clean" flux is quite nasty- LD50 on rats is 4mg/kg. From [this](http://www.ccohs.ca/oshanswers/chemicals/ld50.html) occupational health and safety site:

> What does LD50 mean?
>
> LD stands for "Lethal Dose". LD50 is the amount of a material, given
>   all at once, which causes the death of 50% (one half) of a group of
>   test animals. The LD50 is one way to measure the short-term poisoning
>   potential (acute toxicity) of a material.
>
> Toxicologists can use many kinds of animals but most often testing is
>   done with rats and mice. It is usually expressed as the amount of
>   chemical administered (e.g., milligrams) per 100 grams (for smaller
>   animals) or per kilogram (for bigger test subjects) of the body weight
>   of the test animal. The LD50 can be found for any route of entry or
>   administration but dermal (applied to the skin) and oral (given by
>   mouth) administration methods are the most common.

The reasons for only washing hands before breaks and after work is so that you don't ingest lead from handling food etc. or other contact with mucous membranes.

Solder *paste* is considerably easier to ingest, so more care is called for.

Also, if you are **pregnant or could become pregnant**, much more care should be taken.

Comment: Does this mean I have to wash my hands every time I attach a weight to my fishing line?

Comment: You should make a habit of washing your hands after handling bare lead weights and before you handle a sandwich or whatever. Not every time you touch a weight. But you'd want to do that anyway, right? There are probably more extreme views out there. Some workplaces bag all exposed lead so the oxide doesn't flake off and get into the environment.

Comment: 50 years of holding parts with my lips and stripping wire with my teeth and I can still sort of type (and casting bullets, fish and dive belt weights). I'm more worried about the lead compound used to get red glaze for the table ware and wine cups of the Caesars. And whatever happened to all the chelation therapy that was supposed to remove it all?

Comment: @C. Towne Springer: chelation agents are still in use but they are quite toxic by themselves. And once the brain damage is done, no chelation will restore your brain function.

Answer (score 3):

It has only been more recently agreed that there is NO acceptable level do lead exposure and thus those big warnings on all of the California bound products. Open pit mining and it's affects on ground water lead levels is what has fueled some of the concern and research.

The main points of concern have already been pointed out in the various answers, but as a family doctor I will summarize my concerns with lead exposes:

1) length of exposure and cumulative exposure which for you is very little.

2) type of exposure: handlig lead is nothing compared to ingesting it or breathing it in.

3) Age: Children and pregnancy are of greater concern

In other words: don't worry about it!

To be safe: don't do it again!

By the way, long term exposure to breathing in the fumes that are made when solder is melted has been linked to asthma. This is likely from the flux.

Comment: Breathing flux fumes certainly aggravates existing asthma, in my experience. For some perverse reason the plume likes to curl up into your face unless you use a small fan or extractor. http://www.google.ca/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=Zh-mFRSnMvfnWM&tbnid=6btGfHMc8movsM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fitm%2FBenchtop-Solder-Smoke-Absorber-Remover-Fume-Extractor-%2F230942169688&ei=JlI6U_uyC5TC2gWbrYHoDA&bvm=bv.63934634,d.b2I&psig=AFQjCNEmjWbMjDripqRLAKOfDFNLr5ixlw&ust=1396417445191686

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany - Very cool unit that you provided a link to.  It actually filters out the fumes vs just blowing them away with a fan - what a novel idea!

Answer (score 1):

You're safe.

Although I'm statistically insignificant my exposure might give you some comfort:

- 10 years old, chewed on the lead plate included in the electronics lab kit.
- Chewed on lead pellets for air gun (I like to chew).
- My co worker accidentally dropped 1dl of solder lead in the dishwasher at work, the lead lay in the machine for a couple of washes and probably contaminated the coffee cups...
- Lots of soldering without gloves or fume extractor.

I'm still alive. Although I do get rashes sometimes from flux fumes and residues.

Comment: No clean flux fumes are the nastiest...

Comment: This is a terrible answer. My father tells me how in his day they played with mercury, didn't wear seatbelts, worked with formaldehyde, tore up asbestos and sprinkled lead paint dust on their corn flakes and "I survived." Yes, and a *statistically significant* portion of people got brain damage, died in crashes, got cancer, lead poisoning etc.. "I've never worn a helmet & I ride every day" well gee that must be the best approach then. Please let's stick with numbers, not meaningless anecdotes.

Comment: I think it should be stressed that "occasional" exposure is usually of little concern, but that repeating occasional exposure becomes chronic exposure that leads to organ damage (mostly brain and kidneys). Being still alive is no proof of no damage.

Answer (score 0):

I stand more chance of being hit by a 96 bus on a Friday afternoon than die from lead poisoning from soldering which I have done for over 50 years.

The unleaded stuff looks horrible, it cracks and causes faults. I will always use proper solder till the day I hang up my soldering iron.
I also use  old type plumbers flux, as the new fluxes do not do the job very well.
I repair vintage wireless sets and I am sure I would have come across all sorts of so called dangerous products, I am still healthy, got all my own teeth which still works as a good set of wire strippers.
so there it is, i am getting fed up with many scientists telling us that everything is bad for you. Sliding down a mountain side on two bits of wood is bad for you! jumping out of an aircraft can be bad for you. or even crossing the road.